# Solution to sixth order equation

Tags: polynomials, factorization, rootfinding

I'm dealing with the expression $x = \frac{1}{3}y(y+1)(2y+1)^2(2y^2+2y+1)$. What is this approximately, if one is explicitly writing y in terms of x? There's no general formula for sixth powers unfortunately.

Also can one given an approximation of this so that the difference between the true y and the approximation go to zero? (Not just the ratio).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For $x,y>0$ there is a unique solution $y(x)$ to $x = \frac{1}{3}y(y+1)(2y+1)^2(2y^2+2y+1)$ given by
$$y=\tfrac{1}{2} 3^{-1/3} \sqrt{\frac{\left(\sqrt{11664 x^2-3}+108 x\right)^{2/3}+3^{1/3}}{\bigl(\sqrt{11664 x^2-3}+108 x\bigr)^{1/3}}}- \tfrac{1}{2}.$$
Here is a plot of $y$ versus $x$.

[image]

Comment: To give an idea of how you can come up with this, you can realize that substituting $z=y+\frac{1}{2}$, you obtain $x$ as an even function of $z$ (a way to suspect this is noticing that the roots of the given degree 6 polynomial are symmetric respect to $-\frac{1}{2}$), so you can call another variable $t=z^2$ and then you have $x$ as a cubic polynomial in $t$, which allows you to use Cardano´s formula for the cubic equation.

Comment: Since the RHS is strictly increasing, zero at zero and tends to infinity, existence and uniqueness of a positive solution is evident.

Comment: Note that $108^{2}=11664$. By introducing $\xi:=108 x$ the solution's formula becomes rather compact.